# Using createDefaultAxes() only show a small X-axis and small Y-axis with 1 value in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts

According to `QT` documentation

> **void QChart::createDefaultAxes()**
> Creates axes for the chart based on
> the series that have already been added to the chart. Any axes
> previously added to the chart will be deleted.
>
> Note: This function **has to be called after all series have been added**
> **to the chart**. The axes created by this function will NOT get
> automatically attached to any series added to the chart after this
> function has been called. A series with no axes attached will by
> default scale to utilize the entire plot area of the chart, which can
> be confusing if there are other series with properly attached axes
> also present.

So then I first create my series after I have removed all series from `qChart` object and clear `pwm_serie`, `ao_serie`, `ai_serie`, `dai_serie`, `encoder_serie` and `input_capture_serie`.

```
void Easy_chart::create_new_series(){
    qChart.removeAllSeries();
    pwm_serie.clear();
    ao_serie.clear();
    ai_serie.clear();
    dai_serie.clear();
    encoder_serie.clear();
    input_capture_serie.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < PWM_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        pwm_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
    for(int i = 0; i < AO_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        ao_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
    for(int i = 0; i < AI_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        ai_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
    for(int i = 0; i < DAI_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        dai_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
    for(int i = 0; i < ENCODER_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        encoder_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
    for(int i = 0; i < INPUT_CAPTURE_SERIES_LENGTH; i++)
        input_capture_serie.append(new QLineSeries());
}
```

Done that!
Then I fill my `series`. For every new `value`, I call this function.

```
qChart.addSeries(append_to_series("PWM", pwm_serie.at(index), index, value));
```

Where `pwm_serie.at(index)` can be an arbitrary `serie`. The `index` is what type of serie we are going to use because the series are declared as:

```
private:
    QChart qChart;
    QList<QLineSeries*> pwm_serie;
    QList<QLineSeries*> ao_serie;
    QList<QLineSeries*> ai_serie;
    QList<QLineSeries*> dai_serie;
    QList<QLineSeries*> encoder_serie;
    QList<QLineSeries*> input_capture_serie;
    int show_samples;
```

Then I append values to the `serie`. What this function does is:

1. Add a name to the series e.g `PWM0` or `DAI2` depending on `label` and `index`
2. Append values to the `serie` if length of the`serie` is less than `show_samples`, else it will just replace the values.

And this function return back the pointer `QLineSeries*`.

```
QLineSeries* Easy_chart::append_to_series(const QString& label, QLineSeries* serie, int index, float value){
    serie->setName(label + QString::number(index) + "(" + QString::number(value) + ")");
    int count = serie->count();
    if(count >= show_samples){
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if(i == count - 1)
                serie->replace(i, i, value);
            else
                serie->replace(i, i, serie->at(i+1).y());
    }else{
        serie->append(count, value);
    }
    return serie;
}
```

Then finally, I'm calling the famous function of `QT`: `createDefaultAxes();`

But then It looks like this.

**Questions:**

1. I have 10 values in my `PMW0` series. Why does I only se `1` value?
2. Why aren't the axis automatically scaled?

[image]

**How to reproduce this example**

```
easy_chart.set_show_samples(10);
easy_chart.create_new_series();
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 10);
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 12);
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 14);
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 16);
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 19);
easy_chart.append_to_pwm_serie(0, 20);
qChart.createDefaultAxes();
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer. It seems that `QT` have poor design for `Chart` class, but there is a way to walk around this problem.

Once you have add your `serie` to the `chart`, you `MUST` remove it if you want to implmenet the same `serie` that have more appended points. But be aware, if you remove the `serie` from the `chart`, you need to create a `new` serie as well.

```
    QLineSeries* serie = new QLineSeries();
    serie->setName("First serie");
    serie->append(0, 1);
    serie->append(1, 2);
    serie->append(2, 2);
    serie->append(3, 6);
    serie->append(4, 5);
    serie->append(5, 4);
    serie->append(6, 8);
    serie->append(7, 1);
    serie->append(8, 5);
    serie->append(9, 9);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->addSeries(serie);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->createDefaultAxes();
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->removeAllSeries(); // Step 1: Delete the series
    serie = new QLineSeries(); // Step 2: Create new series
    serie->setName("Second serie");
    serie->append(10, 10);
    serie->append(11, 20);
    serie->append(12, 20);
    serie->append(13, 60);
    serie->append(14, 50);
    serie->append(15, 40);
    serie->append(16, 80);
    serie->append(17, 10);
    serie->append(18, 50);
    serie->append(19, 90);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->addSeries(serie);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->createDefaultAxes();
```

[image]

Here is an example if you want to add multiple series to the chart.

```
    QLineSeries* serie = new QLineSeries();
    serie->setName("First serie");
    serie->append(0, 1);
    serie->append(1, 2);
    serie->append(2, 2);
    serie->append(3, 6);
    serie->append(4, 5);
    serie->append(5, 4);
    serie->append(6, 8);
    serie->append(7, 1);
    serie->append(8, 5);
    serie->append(9, 9);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->addSeries(serie);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->createDefaultAxes();
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->removeAllSeries();
    serie = new QLineSeries();
    serie->setName("Second serie");
    serie->append(10, 10);
    serie->append(11, 20);
    serie->append(12, 20);
    serie->append(13, 60);
    serie->append(14, 50);
    serie->append(15, 40);
    serie->append(16, 80);
    serie->append(17, 10);
    serie->append(18, 50);
    serie->append(19, 90);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->addSeries(serie);
    QLineSeries* serie2 = new QLineSeries();
    serie2->setName("Third serie");
    serie2->append(10, 15);
    serie2->append(11, 24);
    serie2->append(12, 21);
    serie2->append(13, 66);
    serie2->append(14, 151);
    serie2->append(15, 40);
    serie2->append(16, 84);
    serie2->append(17, 12);
    serie2->append(18, 55);
    serie2->append(19, -45);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->addSeries(serie2);
    ui->chart_graphicsView->chart()->createDefaultAxes();
```

[image]